# Where are these config options coming from?

Tags: git, config

I have the following Git configurations regarding `mergetool`:

```
C:\Users\Me\Documents\GitHub\MyProject [branch-1]> git config --list | grep mergetool
alias.mt=mergetool
mergetool.prompt=false
mergetool.keepbackup=false
mergetool.bc3.cmd="c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 3/bcomp.exe" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$BASE" "   $MERGED"
mergetool.bc3.trustexitcode=true
mergetool.p4.cmd="c:/program files/Perforce/p4merge.exe" "$BASE" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
mergetool.p4.trustexitcode=false
mergetool.kdiff3.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\KDiff3\kdiff3.exe
mergetool.kdiff3.prompt=true
mergetool.kdiff3.keepbackup=false
mergetool.kdiff3.trustexitcode=false
```

I am most concerned about how `mergetool.bc3` and `mergetool.p4` got in there. These configurations are not in the global `gitconfig` file nor are they in the local one. Is there another place where `git config --list` fetches configuration data other than the global and local repository settings?

EDIT: I am using Windows

Answer (score 0):

git looks in at least one other file, a system level config.  I'm not sure where that would be on Windows but you could edit it with `git config -e --system` and git will open the file in your editor.  Similarly to find user and local you can use `git config -e --global` and `git config -e` respectively.

From the `FILES` section of `git help config`

> $GIT_DIR/config
>       Repository specific configuration file.
>
> ~/.gitconfig
>       User-specific configuration file. Also called "global" configuration file.
>
> $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config
>       Second user-specific configuration file. If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is not set or empty, $HOME/.config/git/config will be
>       used. Any single-valued variable set in this file will be overwritten by whatever is in ~/.gitconfig. It is a good
>       idea not to create this file if you sometimes use older versions of Git, as support for this file was added fairly
>       recently.
>
> $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig
>       System-wide configuration file.